# How to add only checked checkboxes added in array list?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to insert checkbox text only if they are checked. How to do that?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString("txt")
    Dim splitted As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(",")
    For Each id As String In splitted
        Dim ctrl As Control = Page.FindControl("checkbox" & id)

        If Not ctrl Is Nothing Then
            Dim chkbox As CheckBox = DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox)
            chkbox.Enabled = False
            Dim arrList As New ArrayList()
            'populate the list with some temp values
            arrList.Add(CheckBox1.Text)
            arrList.Add(CheckBox2.Text)

            'databind the list to our repeater
            Repeater1.DataSource = arrList
            Repeater1.DataBind()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This code will add all checkboxes whether it is checked or not !

Can any body do that... so that only checked checkboxes would be added in array list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this is what you are expecting?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 

TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString("txt") 
Dim splitted As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(",") 

For Each id As String In splitted 
    Dim ctrl As Control = Page.FindControl("checkbox" & id)

        If Not ctrl Is Nothing Then 
            Dim chkbox As CheckBox = DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox) 
            chkbox.Enabled = False 
            Dim arrList As New ArrayList() 
            'populate the list with some temp values 
            if chkbox.Checked then
                  arrList.Add(chkbox.Text) 
            end if

            'databind the list to our repeater 
            Repeater1.DataSource = arrList 
            Repeater1.DataBind() 
        End If 
    Next 
End Sub
```